# Downloading a binary file with RestKit 0.20.x

Tags: ios, download, restkit-0.20

I have seen a lot of major changes with the RestKit framework in version 0.20.x for the iOS platform.
The one thing I haven't found so far on the web is an example of how to download a binary file with the new version of RestKit.

I need to send a JSON object to a REST service and expect a binary file in return. Would seem simple, wouldn't it but for some reason RestKit only expects JSON (and the common internet content types such as XML) to come back.
The JSON object essentially is a request object telling the service which image it should go and get for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately I have managed to use the underlying AFNNetworking framework to help me with this and leverage the RestKit serializer to produce the request object I needed.

```c
MyRequestClass *request = // ... get my request class instance
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
NSMutableURLRequest *downloadRequest = [manager requestWithObject:request method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:ROUTE_URL_MY_SERVICE parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:downloadRequest];

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Use my success callback with the binary data and MIME type string
    callback(operation.responseData, operation.response.MIMEType, nil);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Error callback
    callback(nil, nil, error);
}];
[manager.HTTPClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:requestOperation];
```

Comment: Best piece of code I found for downloading a simple preview image using the latest restkit, thanks :-)

Comment: How can  I map to MyResponseClass if I receive a JSON?

Comment: This is for sending JSON to receive binary. If you want to map the response object (in JSON form) to a class, you will need to use `RKObjectManager` to make a POST call or whatever and let Restkit perform the mapping. The restkit website has some examples on doing that (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/).